# Auto grow background in CSS with Text Size

Tags: css

I have never been strong on CSS so hoping someone can solve this little issue.

So I have an image to which I add a opaque black background to it at the bottom and then add text inside the background. Its fine for 1 line, but when the headline text rollovers it wont auto grow.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="image">
        <img src="images/MayorMaking.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="imgBackground">
            <div class="imgText">
                This is a really long text sentence that goes over 2 lines, what you think will happen?
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .image { 
        position: relative; 
        width: 480px; /* for IE 6 */
    }

    .imgBackground  
    {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        min-height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }
    .imgText
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        color: White;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

</style>
```

As you can see, I have tried to add a min-height to .imgBackground but that isnt working.

Any help would be awesome, thank you

Comment: can you put it in jsFiddle?

Comment: dont you need a max-height to.... or else it doesnt know if it has to grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
.imgText
    {
    color: White;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `bottom:0` from `.imgBackground` css class

```
.imgBackground {
position: absolute;
/*bottom: 0;*/
}
```

Remove these properties as well

```
.imgText
{
    /*position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;*/
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akjRA/10/)

Comment: The background still didnt grow and the opacity stopped working :(

Comment: @MarkCooney I have update my answer and JSFiddle. Please look into that and let me know what else you want.

Comment: Just added to fiddle, first time ive used it, something not quite right: http://jsfiddle.net/ElyCity/Jbq6a/

Comment: What's your expected result? please let me know.. so that I can make changes according to that..

Answer (score 0):

OK sorted, I readded the bottom: 0 to imgBackground then removed the absolute and bottom: 0 from imgText and working great now!! Thanks